# How to get country name based on latitude and longitude using Leaflet.?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I am just showing latitude and longitude,clicking on map using lightning component. I want to show also name of country and state, in which zip code exists. Please give me solution

Component-

```
<aura:component >
   <ltng:require styles="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.css"
   scripts="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.js"
   afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
   <div id="map"></div>
  </aura:component >
```

JSController-

```
jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
var popup = L.popup();
function onMapClick(e) {    
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(map);
}
map.on('click', onMapClick);}
```

Comment: Hi Satyakam! You may want to [edit] additional information in to your question. The way this question is written, it seems like [so] would be a better fit for your question, because this is not specifically salesforce.com related. If it is related to salesforce.com technology, for example, because [tag:locker-service] is causing an error, please let us know what the error was so we can better assist you. Also, have you read the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AtulRajguru suggested, I tried to create a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/U6Gaa/168/) link to get a similar experience. Hope this helps.

The click function method is as below.

```
map.on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({ url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+e.latlng.lat+','+e.latlng.lng+'&sensor=true',
             success: function(data){
                 var state = data.results[0].address_components[5].long_name;
                 var country = data.results[0].address_components[6].long_name;
                 var zip = data.results[0].address_components[7].long_name;
                 $('.leaflet-popup-content').text(state+' '+country+' '+zip);
                 console.log(data.results[0]);
             }
    });
   popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent('').openOn(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many API that provide the address into based on lat long. One good example is from our best friend google

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.5470880,73.8978420

This returns JSON like below. you can then parse this JSON and get the required info:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "25/A",
               "short_name" : "25/A",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Carnation Society",
               "short_name" : "Carnation Society",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nilanjali Society",
               "short_name" : "Nilanjali Society",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "short_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "411006",
               "short_name" : "411006",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "25/A, Carnation Society, Nilanjali Society, Kalyani Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra 411006, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.54709,
               "lng" : 73.89785999999999
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5484389802915,
                  "lng" : 73.8992089802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5457410197085,
                  "lng" : 73.89651101970848
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ5_m14hrBwjsRJW7XDe8sLbA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Carnation Society",
               "short_name" : "Carnation Society",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Prathamesh Society",
               "short_name" : "Prathamesh Society",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "short_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "411006",
               "short_name" : "411006",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Carnation Society, Prathamesh Society, Kalyani Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra 411006, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5473972,
                  "lng" : 73.90067049999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5436113,
                  "lng" : 73.8971243
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.545674,
               "lng" : 73.8988731
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5473972,
                  "lng" : 73.90067049999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5436113,
                  "lng" : 73.8971243
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJnZo2yRrBwjsRiEK_xjiwFkw",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Prathamesh Society",
               "short_name" : "Prathamesh Society",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "short_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "411006",
               "short_name" : "411006",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Prathamesh Society, Kalyani Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra 411006, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5474382,
                  "lng" : 73.90604400000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5428442,
                  "lng" : 73.89702579999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.5445409,
               "lng" : 73.90144389999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5474382,
                  "lng" : 73.90604400000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5428442,
                  "lng" : 73.89702579999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJvd07_Q_BwjsRaogYQtLt2j4",
         "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "short_name" : "Kalyani Nagar",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kalyani Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5550939,
                  "lng" : 73.912824
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.540265,
                  "lng" : 73.89014
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.5463286,
               "lng" : 73.9033139
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5550939,
                  "lng" : 73.912824
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.540265,
                  "lng" : 73.89014
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJxZBnkBDBwjsRcpq1NoUtYVY",
         "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Prabhag 36",
               "short_name" : "Prabhag 36",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.6357545,
                  "lng" : 73.98645689999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.4134784,
                  "lng" : 73.7394779
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.5204303,
               "lng" : 73.8567437
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.6357545,
                  "lng" : 73.98645689999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.4134784,
                  "lng" : 73.7394779
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "411006",
               "short_name" : "411006",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Pune, Maharashtra 411006, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5755006,
                  "lng" : 73.9066698
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5314081,
                  "lng" : 73.8541996
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.5527212,
               "lng" : 73.8896445
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5755006,
                  "lng" : 73.9066698
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5314081,
                  "lng" : 73.8541996
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ90BvYufAwjsR1EdhoTDPvZw",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.38404,
                  "lng" : 75.16309
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 17.89324,
                  "lng" : 73.32352
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.6832564,
               "lng" : 74.0300122
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.38404,
                  "lng" : 75.1447465
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 17.89324,
                  "lng" : 73.32352
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.028441,
                  "lng" : 80.890924
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 15.6024121,
                  "lng" : 72.659363
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.7514798,
               "lng" : 75.7138884
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.0279091,
                  "lng" : 80.890924
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 15.6024121,
                  "lng" : 72.659363
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.5087008,
                  "lng" : 97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.4626999,
                  "lng" : 68.1097
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 20.593684,
               "lng" : 78.96288
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.5087008,
                  "lng" : 97.39498069999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.7535159,
                  "lng" : 68.16288519999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```